# Search a file on a linux server with a php

Tags: php, linux

I´am with a problem for search a file on a linux server, i try to read a directory but i can´t set permission for the script on php read that directory.
The problem is not the permission by himself, because i set `chmod -R 777 [file]` and this don´t work, for make the problem worse that directory is a link to another directory so i don´t know if the problem is the origin or the destination.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, does the error specify a line of code, if so please paste this line of code into your question.

Comment: symlinks always have permission 777, so any access denied errors comes from the file/directory the link points at, not the link itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP and Apache must be in a group that has access to that directory.